# iPhone UI: Dropdown Picker with footer for each Item

Tags: iphone, ios

I've done this on android using custom layouts for menus. How do I create a multiline dropdown Picker where each line item has additional string as footer?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

You need to implement this delegate method and in it return your custom view.

Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3aviewForRow%3aforComponent%3areusingView%3a)

Comment: Make sure to layout your custom row view so it has some whitespace left and right to not collide with the surrounding "roll" UI. Also, a non-opaque background for the labels is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` delegate method.